# inject variable into mysql query in a bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I am writing a bash script that executes a query called UpdateLicense:

```
#!/bin/bash  

license=$(<license_key.txt)
echo "$license"

mysql -u user -ppassword<<UpdateLicense

UPDATE propertytext SET propertyvalue = '<license_variable>' WHERE id = 112;

UpdateLicense
```

I have a file license.txt which I saved as a string in a variable license.

I would like to use this variable and inject it in the query in order to keep it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#!/bin/bash  

license=$(<license_key.txt)
echo "$license"

mysql -u user -ppassword<<UpdateLicense
set @my_var='$license'
UPDATE propertytext SET propertyvalue = @my_var WHERE id = 112;

UpdateLicense
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However it didn't work for me!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by using the following query line:

```
mysql -u user -ppassword<<UpdateLicense
UPDATE propertytext SET propertyvalue = '< $license' WHERE id = 112;
UpdateLicense
```